# Result of Replace function isn´t used / cannot be applied

Tags: java, replace

I want to iterate over two input strings that being stored in an array. Next, I want to replace all umlauts (ä,ö,ü, ...) by its "aquivalents" a,o,u.
Somehow the changes seem to not be applied to the array. How´s that possible and what to do in order to fix this?
Thaanks for helping me!!!

```
        String[] liste = {wort1, wort2};
        for(int i =0; i<2; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<liste[i].length(); j++) {
                String buchstabe = liste[i].substring(j,j+1);
                switch(buchstabe) {
                    case "ä":
                    case "Ä":
                        buchstabe.replace("ä", "a");
                        break;
                    case "ö":
                    case "Ö":
                        buchstabe.replace("ö", "o");
                        break;
                    case "ü":
                    case "Ü":
                        buchstabe.replace("ü", "u");
                        break;
                    case "ß":
                        buchstabe.replace("ß", "ss");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. When you call replace it returns a copy. You never re-assign the values in `liste`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thanks, but even if I reassign the value ```buchstabe = buchstabe.replace```, it says the value is never being used. Do I need to return something?

Comment: I would replace `ä` with `ae`, same for the other Umlaute - we do not know what else is happening with `buchstabe`, by that error, probably nothing. So better not use `buchstabe` at all, and apply the `replace` to `liste[i]` as already commented and  in answer

Comment: @MartinMüller you question omits the necessary code to know how to fix it. How do you know the strings aren't being changed?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in are immutable in Java, so you can't **change** a string.
The [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method creates a new strings and returns it, so you'll need to set the `buchstabe` variable to the newly created string:

```java
buchstabe = buchstabe.replace("ä", "a");
```

BTW.: You don't need to go through each character individually, the `replace` method replaces **all occurrences** in a string.

The replace method does not care whether the *needle* is present in your *haystack*. Therefore you can also save the checks whether e.g. an "ä" is contained in your string:

```java
String[] liste = {wort1, wort2};
for(int i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
    liste[i] = liste[i].replace("ä", "a");
}
```